# Groovy/Java: Cost of changing a List<Object> to Set<Object>

Tags: java, collections, groovy

Is it computationally expensive to change a large `List` of objects to a `Set`?

Update:

I asked this question because I can choose to define a field in my class either as `Set` or `List` and I went with `List` There are some cases that I do things that require the `List` to be cast to `Set`. I was wondering if it is a better idea to cast the `List` when needed or use `Set` in the first place.

Comment: It depends on the Set. If it's a HashSet, it's O(n). If it's a TreeSet, it's O(n log n).

Comment: You will re-copy the references. It will depend of 1) The cost of reading from the list. 2) The cost of writing to the Set. It depends of both implementations.

Comment: I had never had performance problems caused by such transformations. Unless you do this really often and on huge collections, it is not a problem. If you have a good reason to have a List on a side and a Set on the other side, just do the copy.

Comment: You should really be only using a `Set` if you have an actual use for it; is uniqueness of elements a requirement in your collection? Do you perform operations such as `.contains()` and friends often?

Comment: @fge is `.contains()` cheaper in `Set` than `List`?

Comment: Possibly yes, since uniqueness in a `Set` is generally guaranteed by equals()/hashCode(); which means that if your elements have a suitable implementation for each (the default implementaiton is suitable) then a `Set` implementation will directly answer "no" if the argument's hash code is different from any other in the set. But again, that depends on the implementation.

Comment: Moderators: I have updated my question and I guess it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

The cost depends on the specific implementation, but for constructing a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) from a collection, the cost of construction is `O(n)`, assuming that `hashCode()` and `equals()` are O(1) and assuming that the iteration cost of the source collection is `O(n)`.